# Change the expiry time of PHPSESSID Cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have been at this for a day now, but nothing seems to be working.
What I want to do: change the expiry time of the session cookie PHPSESSID, when a particular checkbox is checked , how do I do this ?
I have tried:

ini_set()

session_set_cookie_params()

setcookie()

but nothing works . Can someone please please help me here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To specify the session lifetime, server side, either apply the following command

```
  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 30*60); // expires in 30 minutes
```

or set it in your `php.ini` file.

To set the session cookie lifetime, client side, either let it as it is (0, will die when the browser is closed), or

```
  ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 30*60); // 30 minutes
```

or in the `php.ini`.

If you choose to use `ini_set()`, be sure to place the commands *before* `session_start()` is called.

Note that the `ini_set` function sets configuration option(s) [during the script execution time only](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

Regarding the checkbox and having a dynamic setting of the session lifetime, you could

- use [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) to store a setting shared by all PHP processes, that will last until the PHP server is down
- write a value in a file somewhere that you load at the start of scripts (expensive) and set the value

(each script will have to `ini_set()` once before `session_start()`)

Comment: thanks, I now understand the problem was that ini_set needs to be before session_start() . but I can't figure out how to change the value of an existing phpsessid cookie..

Comment: Yes this does the trick for me. For my ajax calls I needed a way to detect if the session is expired. Note that you need to delete the cookie with the wrong expires date before testing.